# Pseudocode: "If not" control structure

Tags: algorithms, pseudocode

I use the following packages:

```
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
```

to display pseudocode of some algorithms in my latex document. For conditionals I use the follow

```
\If{success = 0}
\State \Return{$\emptyset$}
\EndIf
```

Now, this renders the `if` and `endif` keywords in bold using the same typeface as the one used for all the other control structures. My question is the following: How can I render `if not` instead of `if`? So my code would read something like:

```
\IfNot{success}
\State \Return{$\emptyset$}
\EndIf
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take all the details associated with `\If` (within [`algpseudocode.sty`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/algorithmicx/algpseudocode.sty)) and add your own `\IfNot`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\algnewcommand\algorithmicnot{\textbf{not}}
\algdef{SE}[IF]{IfNot}{EndIf}[1]{\algorithmicif\ \algorithmicnot\ #1\ \algorithmicthen}{\algorithmicend\ \algorithmicif}%

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithmic}
  \If{success = 0}
    \State \Return $\emptyset$
  \EndIf
  \IfNot{success}
    \State \Return $\emptyset$
  \EndIf
\end{algorithmic}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This did exactly what I was looking for, thanks!